# Zookeeper cluster with two nodes

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have two nodes and setting up zookeeper (3.5.3) for cluster . Recommended is 3 But i dont have option to get one more node .

Please suggest is there any option by reconfig or weight change etc .

Comment: Did you consider running multiple zookeepers on a single node?  https://serverfault.com/questions/715469/how-to-add-second-zookeeper-to-same-machine

Comment: env is vm ,not docker .i am trying to use weight and dynamic config change at runtime so that when one of the node goes for graceful shutdown it checks if peer is follower then change the peers weight .if peer is leader dont change the config . But this is not correct solution it is workaround. it wont work when n/w partition and abrupt shutdown case.

Comment: of course you can run a two-nodes cluster directly. when you got more, you can dynamic reconfiguration https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.3-beta/zookeeperReconfig.html to add it to the cluster

Answer (score 0):

If it is for demo/prototype/experimental purposes, I would suggest you to use vagrant.
I have done this in my host linux machine. I have done a repository and the code is [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/VBoxes/tree/master/simple-zk-quorum). If you have linux machine, all that you have to do is `vagrant up`. Please try and let me know your comments/questions.